# Where can I get Traveller 5 and when?

Tags: traveller

I'm very interested in the Traveller 5 game. I missed its [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/traveller5/traveller-5th-edition). Is the game available? If so where? If not, where and when will it be available for purchase?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it has time-limited relevance.

Answer (score 9):

It's available.  See the website of Marc Miller's **Far Future Enterprises** at http://www.farfuture.net/

or online retailers like http://www.gameslore.com/acatalog/PR_Traveller_5_RPG_Core_Rulebook.html

Answer (score 6):

Marc Miller, doing business as Far Future Enterprises (FFE), sells the game both in hardcover and on CD directly, and through distributors. The game has been out since Q4 2013.

FFE's point of sale is http://farfuture.net. The T5 materials are on the front page, and at present, the T5 line includes the hardcover (at $75), the CD-ROM (at $35), a pair of dice sets (3/4" d6's - big and chunky), and a couple deckplan sets.

CD-ROM purchasers will be eligible for a very low cost upgrade when Marc completes the revision to the T5 rules.

The Hardcover and Deckplans may be available via your local retailers; the CD-ROM is available only from FFE.

The Deckplans and rulebook are available electronically via [DrivethroughRPG](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/browse.php?manufacturers_id=4). Note that the physical set is the 5-ship set; the "set 1" on DTRPG is a subset of that.

Disclaimer: I run FFE's Traveller Bulletin Board. I am not an employee, but a volunteer.

Comment: The information I have is limited, even as an insider, and is that Marc's revising a few areas for clarity, prior to producing the T5 Player's Book. Most notably combat. There is a lot of errata. There are ongoing discussions at TravellerRPG.com. (which is the site I run for Marc.)

Comment: When originally posted, this answer indicated the T5 rules were being revised (in the CD-ROM upgrade section). Is that still the case? Wikipedia suggests an "interim" version went out in June 2015.